# Why need config MultipartFilter after config CommonsMultipartResolver when uploading file using spring?

Tags: java, spring, file

I'm developing an API for file uploading, and need an proxy. when not using proxy, only add config:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes 400m -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="419430400" />
</bean>
```

API will work correctly as follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tags/build", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object buildTag(String repoName, String tag, @RequestParam(value = "dockerFile", required = true) MultipartFile dockerFile,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

but add an proxy, it doesn't work, proxy:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
@ResponseBody
public String mirror(@RequestBody(required = false) String body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException {
    ...
    try {
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new CloudClientHttpRequestFactory(30000, 5000));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), entity, String.class);
        String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
```

but when I add MultipartFilter in proxy web.xml, it can work also. why? Is there any body can help me? Thanks in advance. I have googled, but can't find satisfied answer.

Comment: What is this `CloudClientHttpRequestFactory`?

Comment: I'm sorry to explain it,  it's an class extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory